# Serialized object graphs for arranging unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, serialization, tdd

I have an application where the problem domain is represented by domain objects which are highly interrelated. I have split the domain into a few aggregate root objects which helps impose order on the model, however arranging preconditions for unit tests is arduous as creating instances of these aggregate roots requires creating a great number of supporting objects that are referenced.

I want to write repeatable, isolated unit tests that exercise the application without the need for external dependencies (and ideally without writing a huge chunk of code).

I think these are my options. Any preference, or other suggestions?

1. Write build scripts that setup the project database and INSERT known data into it, against which unit tests are executed. This is my least favorite option as it introduces an external dependency (and therefore isn't a true unit test) as well as many more potential failures. It also doesn't isolate the business function being tested because the fault could lie within the data access code.
2. Create re-usable factories that create domain objects with a known state, against which unit tests are run. This will work well, but means lots of boilerplate code to be written, and therefore lots to change when/if the model changes.
3. (Current method) Create binary serializations of my aggregate root objects into files that are checked in with the test project. The unit tests deserialize them for their tests. The downside to this is that if the underlying type changes deserialization will fail and all the serialized files have to be re-created.
4. Suck it up and write a custom serializer that serializes the graphs to XML files that can be checked in to the solution and deserialized at test time. Like 2, this means alot of up-front boilerplate code to be written, but maintenance is easier as the serialized state can be edited easily with a text editor if the model changes.
5. UR DOIN IT RONG. The fact that your domain objects are so highly referential is the main problem. Simplify it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Write build scripts that setup the project database and INSERT known data into it, against which unit tests are executed. This is my least favorite option as it introduces an external dependency (and therefore isn't a true unit test) as well as many more potential failures. It also doesn't isolate the business function being tested because the fault could lie within the data access code.

The *"integration not unit"* is minor issue (especially when compared with *"test or not test"*), I wouldn't worry about that. There are other, more serious problems with this approach:

- Writing scripts. You'll most likely end up coding SQL by hand which requires a lot of discipline especially when model is complex. Typos are painful, it's hard to debug/detect problems, you need to take IDE/tools into consideration too.
- When your model changes, you'll be fixing those SQL scripts, which raises same issues - typos, hard to spot errors and so on, lack of IDE support.

Overall, this approach is **expensive in terms of maintainability**.

> Create re-usable factories that create domain objects with a known state, against which unit tests are run. This will work well, but means lots of boilerplate code to be written, and therefore lots to change when/if the model changes.

Decent approach, you should investigate libraries that make this process easier (hint: [**AutoFixture**](https://github.com/AutoFixture), [**NBuilder**](http://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/)).

> (Current method) Create binary serializations of my aggregate root objects into files that are checked in with the test project. The unit tests deserialize them for their tests. The downside to this is that if the underlying type changes deserialization will fail and all the serialized files have to be re-created.

Same issue as with build-scripts one - changes will be expensive.

> Suck it up and write a custom serializer that serializes the graphs to XML files that can be checked in to the solution and deserialized at test time. Like 2, this means alot of up-front boilerplate code to be written, but maintenance is easier as the serialized state can be edited easily with a text editor if the model changes.

This is essentially the same solution as your second one, but with XML as man in the middle. Why adding extra layer?

> UR DOIN IT RONG. The fact that your domain objects are so highly referential is the main problem. Simplify it.

Rather unlikely. By their nature domain objects they tend to be complex.

### Conclusion

There are no quick-and-dirty workarounds to such problem. Complex domain means there has to be some extra work done at some point. *Serialization-based* solutions (1, 3, 4), even though some may seem easy now, will only postpone said extra work to the moment when changes are introduced. In almost every case, I'd go with better **flexibility** and **readiness for changes** (which only second solution offers - if done properly).

Comment: By pointing me at those libraries I think you may have hit upon what I was missing. I will go play. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are talking about is that data is scattered around in the domain-object-graph:

if you want to calculate the price for an invoice you need article-prices, tax-information, customer-specific dicounts, deliveriy specific shipping-consts, ... .

One strategy to handle this complexity is by seperating the logic to get these detail-values from the actual calculation.

The calculation is a internal method with many parameters and minimal dependency to other domainobjects. This can be easily tested because it does not depend on the object graph any more.

An other strategy is to move the complex calculation from the domain into a seperate servicelayer that depend on other service-interfaces. For testing these service-interfaces can be replaced by mocks.